# Options request throws AssertionError error in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-method, http-options-method

I have the following Viewset:

```
class My_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = My_Serializer
    queryset = My_Object.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        # The code here is irrelevant
        return Response()

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        # The code here is irrelevant
        my_object = get_object_or_404(My_Object, id=pk)
        return Response(my_object.id)
```

urls.py sample:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/my_object/', My_ViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    path('api/my_object/<int:pk>/', My_ViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})),
]
```

When I try to make OPTIONS request on **api/my_object/** I have the following error:

**AssertionError: Expected view My_ViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.**

Answer (score -1):

This is because you've defined the retrieve method in your My_ViewSet to expect a pk argument, which is used to retrieve a single object from your queryset. However, in your urls.py file, you haven't specified the pk argument in the URL pattern for the list method.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/my_object/', My_ViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    path('api/my_object/<int:pk>/', My_ViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})),
]
```

Comment: my urls.py are exactly the same as in your "answer" and I am not making a GET request, but OPTIONS request